# Can I just use memcpy for those std::is_trivially_move_* things?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

What is the difference between `is_trivially_copy_*` and `is_trivially_move_*`? Can I use memcpy to move construct/assignment `is_trivially_move_*` types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between them is exactly what the standard says it is: are the specific operations trivial. A class can have a trivial copy constructor and a non-trivial move constructor or vice-versa.

However, these traits are *not sufficient* to be substituted with `memcpy`. The standard *only* allows you to use `memcpy` for objects which are [TriviallyCopyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable). Not merely trivially copy constructible, but TriviallyCopyable in full. So the trait you want is `is_trivially_copyable`.

And technically, you should also check to see if the type is copy constructible/assignable, depending on whether you're `memcpy`ing to live objects or not. A TriviallyCopyable type can have a deleted copy constructor or assignment operator, in which case the writer of that class expects that copying of that form can't happen. The more usual case for a TriviallyCopyable type is a deleted copy assignment operator (due perhaps to having a `const` member), in which case you should not `memcpy` to a live object.